# How do i round values inside calc?

Tags: html, css, sass, less

I've set the rem value to:

```
html {
    font-size: calc( 13px + ( (100vw - 767px) / 767 ) );
}
```

It is equal to 13 pixels on 767px wide screens, bigger on bigger screens and smaller on smaller screens.

Everything works like a charm, except that I get weird gaps when animating inline elements with CSS `transform`'s when their size is set with rems. I made a few tests and seems like the problem disappears when I set the rem value to a round value like 13 or 14px. Is there any way to round my expression above?

Comment: Provide working examples.

Comment: There's no real reason for him here to provide a 'working example'. The problem is being described perfectly.

Comment: Well there's not really a point in rounding isn't there, because then you would be losing your fine-grain control and could just as well define two or three media queries with 12px, 13px and 14px font-sizes. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Sub-pixel rounding errors in IE11 are a valid use case for being able to have control over rounding values.

Answer (score 2):

> There is no native **css** method to round `calc`, unless you are
>   using a `scss` (Sass) there is a library of doing that. Check
>   [here](https://gist.github.com/terkel/4373420)

Alternatively, because it's not a good idea to use `calc` if you want to have a "Responsive" font size you can use native methods and units like `em` or `vm` or `vh` etc than `calc` which costs more CPU cycles.

Also, in case you need specific font size in specific screen dimensions you can use `CSS Media queries`. [Here is a good resource](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Example for vw & vh:

> 1vw = 1% of viewport width 
>   1vh = 1% of viewport height 
>   1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller 
>   1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger

See it in action:

[image]

Check [this](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) out for further info

Comment: I agree, and half of the browsers, used by real people, don't support `calc()` anyway.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, seems like it has a decent support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc.

Comment: @sdvnksv Yes, that is a good resource to look up support, I did a quick scan of this url: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc Scroll down to 'Browser compatibility'.

Comment: And to comment the answer, imagine how small general text will be on mobile if I indicate its size with vh directly. This will require additional media queries I want to avoid. While my solution seems to be pretty universal and only increments / decrements the rem value insignificantly depending on the viewport size.

Comment: This would work if the text / vw ratio would be the same on desktop and mobile screens while it is not even close. Also the question was how to round values inside calc, sorry.

Comment: @paokg4, I commented above.

Comment: @sdvnksv Check the updated answer and also consider the case of media queries.

Comment: This answer and @KIKOSoftware's comment are either seriously outdated or completely inaccurate. The CSS `calc()` function has excellent support across browsers and, bar the minor rounding inability, is just as good as the alternatives for a responsive design, especially if the referenced value is different from the viewport size, say an arbitrary value less than the size of the viewport. I use it, along other methods, and it works great.

Comment: @YinCognyto: My comment is clearly outdated, since it was made in 2017.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Ah, ok, that explains it - things have changed since then, it's normal. Thanks for pointing it out.